# How to add sustain to the whole song in MusicXML?

Tags: musicxml

If we have a midi file, and we get the .musicxml file by some method, such as by using MuseScore.  How do we make the whole song as if we pressed on the sustain pedal (of a piano)?  Can we do it globally or must that be add it for each of the note?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by having a piano piece without sustain, and then add sustain to the whole song, and then diff the two `.musicxml` files, and I found under this part:

```xml
  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="1" width="125.73">
      <print> ... </print>
      <attributes> ... </attributes>
      <direction placement="above"> ... </direction>
```

there is this new addition:

```xml
      <direction placement="below">
        <direction-type>
          <pedal type="start" line="yes" default-y="-65.00"/>
        </direction-type>
        <staff>1</staff>
      </direction>
```

There is also one for a `<staff>2</staff>` below as well that looks the same like above but just the `staff` is changed to `2` and it should be for the Bass Staff.